# Separation of variables to solve Laplace's equation for the V in a cube 3D rectangular coordinates

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series, self-learning, 3d, laplacian

Watch this video[Laplacian in 3D](https://youtu.be/_cPU-nf9owk) and tell me whether $C_{n,m}$ missing **y** in the argument of $\cosh{\sqrt{(\frac{n\pi}{a})^2+(\frac{m\pi}{a})^2}}$ in the denominator. So the final answer is $V_{(x,y,z)}=\frac{32V_0}{\pi^2}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1,3,5...}^\infty \displaystyle\sum_{m=1,3,5...}^\infty\frac{\sin{(\frac{n\pi x}{a})\sin{(\frac{m\pi z}{a})}}}{m n}$

So what is your opinion about this? I think math professor in the video forgot to write **y** in the argument of $\cosh$